# How can i test samsung smart TV app?

Tags: javascript, testing, samsung-smart-tv, television, smart-tv

I developed a samsung smart TV app, tested it in samsung emulator, it works fine.

Now how will i test it in a TV, with out uploading it to samsung app store.

Comment: How did you tested in emulator? I cannot find it documented anywhere

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short version is:

1. Use the SDK to build a package and publish it to a web server.
2. Create an account on the TV called "develop".
3. Configure the TV to sync with the IP address of the server you published the application to.
4. Sync the applications.

Full details are available on Samsung's website in the document "[Testing Your Application on a TV](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00013/index.html)". Finding some of those options requires drilling down through a lot of menus.

Note that Samsung released the 4.0 SDK very recently, so you may find that your software doesn't look all that much like what the document describes. You might have to do some guess work to figure out the changes, or just upgrade your development environment to the 4.0 SDK.

An update of the "Testing Your Application on a TV" for different TV versions:

- 2011 http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00013/index.html
- 2013 http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d20/index.html
- 2014 http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00121/index.html

Comment: Thanks, let me go through the doc :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Quentin... Sorry I misunderstood... ;)

Comment: Hi, note that to have  the best results, you should test it on 2011, 2012 and 2013 models + dome BP players, if you ar egoing to support those as well. The procedure for side load changed a bit on 2013 models - see there http://www.mautilus.com/co-noveho-prinasi-samsung-smarttv-2013/

Comment: Also on 2012 you can upload application from USB sticks (like on LG) -  this side loading is however not possible on 2011 models. Also note that since March Samsung do not accept any new applications for 2010 models.

Comment: There is an updated version of the tutorial for 2014 models: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00121/index.html